# Disabled QLabel color or image appearance

Tags: python-3.x, pyqt5, qlabel

I'm trying to resolve for my self the issue stated in this post from 2011:

https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-19008

Using the stylesheet approach does not work however.

What I would like to do (regarding my own GUI project) is ensure that the images on any disabled QLabels appears the same as when those QLabels are enabled.

Any help in resolving this particular problem would be awesome. Thanks.

Comment: So is this issue specific to osx? Because if it is, that is very important information that you have inexplicably left out of both your questions on this subject. Having said that, the linked bug report only discusses the disabled colour of label *text* on osx, and does not mention images at all. So maybe it just has no relevance to what you are trying to do.

Comment: Hi @ekhumoro, it is for Windows. But as you pointed out this may not be the way to go so the alternative is disabling the mouse - Python3 and PyQt5 don't provide this solution that I know of. Would setting the hotspot co-ords of the mouse pointer hotspot to be 'out of bounds' solve this (at the moment the main window is disabled hence the question on disabled QLabels)?

Comment: Why do you need to disable the labels at all? Are they clickable or something? Or are you disabling the whole gui? If so, the simplest solution would be to create a method that disables/enables only those widgets that can take user input.

Comment: Yes @ekhumoro that is what I need. Where would I start to find out about such a method - are there any examples online?

Comment: You will need to show all your gui code. There is no generic solution for this. It's just a matter of disabling/enabling each widget individually.

Comment: OK @ekhumoro, I will do that tomorrow - off to my 'day job'.

Comment: Hi @ekhumoro, I posted the code now.

Comment: That is not much use, because it is not runnable without all the third-party imports. But in any case, it is relatively trivial to create an enable/disable method. Just list all the widgets that you don't want the user to interact with, and call `setEnabled(enable)` on them (where `enable` is a boolean argument of the method).

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So disabling the GUI is a problem if you have custom graphics for all the  widgets because mid-grey boxes appear everywhere. So what is the solution?

Ekhumoro has provided one solution but here is another:

If you are using Animated GIFs there is no problem - they won't turn mid-grey.
If you are using static images (PNGs) all you have to do is make sure the background is transparent so that only the visible image will turn mid-grey for the duration that those graphics are disabled.

This may not be elegant but it is a workaround that can be considered.